# Center elements inside SVG relative to each other-

Tags: javascript, svg, rect

Couldn't find it anywhere else to I might ask here :

I have svg rectangle which inside has other rectangles.

What I want to achieve is to center each of these rectangles in the centre of it's parent and in relation to each other.

If I drag rectangle 1 down I want the other one to move up to keep both of them centered - and same thing happening if I drag the other element down (should push upper one up).

Problem here is that I might have different width/heights and there would be 2 or more elements. Is there any mathematical equationfor that? Or a name that I can look for?

[image]

Comment: There's no "equation" for such a thing. You need to start coding. Create elements, track events (mouse down move ...), get moved element position, calculate its margins, set second rectangle position accordingly ... And if the result of this code is not something you expected... come back and pose new question. Illustrated with code.

Comment: That's what I already did - got it working in like 90%. No need to calculate margins and other stuff you're saying - simple maths but my calculation lack something.

Comment: This is very basic mathematics. `xOffset = (svgWidth - totalChildrenWidth) / 2` and the equivalent for `Y`. Where are you stuck?  Show us your code and we can help debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the 3 rects inside a group and use the group as in the following example

```css
svg{
  border:1px solid;
  width: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 280">
<defs>  
  <g id="rects">
    <rect width="80" height="80"  />
    <rect width="60" height="25" x="10" y="10"  />
    <rect width="60" height="25" x="10" y="45"  />
  </g>
  </defs>
  
  <use xlink:href="#rects" x="10" y="10"  stroke="black" fill="none" />
  <use xlink:href="#rects" x="10" y="100"  stroke="black" fill="none" />
  <use xlink:href="#rects" x="10" y="190"  stroke="black" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This won't be a static thing, but thanks for answer.

They will be dynamically moved - and parent svg and it's child element might have different widths and height.

That's why it needs and mathematical equation - I need to move all other rectangles to match with the one I am dragging.

Comment: I understand that. And as I've told you, you need to put all the elements you need to move together in the same group, and what you move is the group of elements. This way you move them together. Please try changing the x and y for the use elements

Comment: This won't work -> I won't be moving the group of elements but SINGLE element at the time (and trying to center other elements in relation to each other and parent).

Moving all of them at same time and centering them would be simple :)

Comment: Also you got the image wrong, sorry - it's just to demonstrate how other rectangle would move if you drag rect number 1 down :D